# Пустой блок catch

Tags: c#

Здраствуйте! Так как я студент, и студент такой себе, то я не знаю, можна ли оставлять блок catch пустым? Мне просто-напросто надо, чтобы в случае возникновения Exception`а ничего не делалось, а просто продолжалась работа программы. Меня интересует, есть ли какие-то правила или нормы, которые такого не разрешают?

Comment: "Тихий" `catch` может быть череват тем, что вы не узнаете о том что у вас сбой, так что рекомендуется хотя бы писать в лог из блока `catch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На уровне языка — можно, точно так же как и пустой цикл `while`. Программа откомпилируется и не будет ворчать во время выполнения.

Но с точки зрения хорошего дизайна, игнорировать исключения нужно довольно редко. Если вы игнорируете исключения, никто (в том числе и вы) не узнает, что что-то в программе идёт не по плану.

Обычно в случае, если произошло исключение, вам должно захотеться известить об этом как-нибудь вышестоящую логику программы, чтобы она не тыкалась в это место постоянно. Если вам действительно хочется подавить исключение, хотя бы залогируйте проблему. Ну и во взрослых проектах имеет смысл оставить комментарий для других разработчиков, объясняющий, почему вы можете/должны проигнорировать исключение в этом месте.

Answer (score 2):

Пустые блоки `catch` ничем не запрещены. Можете смело использовать их, но учтите, что при возникновении `exception` в коде блока `try`, выполнение закончится на этом месте и перейдет в `catch`.

В таком случае какой-то код в `try` может остаться невыполненным, поэтому будьте осторожны.